# Remotely Access LAN device connected to PPTP VPN router

Tags: networking, router, vpn, routing

I have ubuntu server installed on VPS and I'm using it as PPTP VPN server.
I can connect to the internet normally from my PC , Mobile , etc so the server is working fine.
i have DDWRT router which I use to connect to my VPN server. I have an alarm panel connected to the router with Ethernet to the LAN port of the router.
the problem is I cant access the panel remotely using my VPN server IP and all ports are showing closed even after opining these ports in the server and in the router. What I'm missing ? I know this is possible because other VPN providers offer this service and I already tested it .
my setup :
PPTP VPN local IP : my server IP
PPTP VPN remote IP : 10.1.0.1-100
DDWRT router IP : 192.168.40.1
Alarm Panel IP : 192.168.40.120

Comment: Need a bit more info. Have you set any iptables rules on the ddwrt router?  Can you connect to the router itself over the VPN? On your remote clients you need to make sure that there is no subnet overlap- not the VPN assigned IP address but the IP address of your local connection(s).

Comment: No I did not and I think it is  unnecessary to do that because I already  have account with VPN provider that allow port forwarding. the only thing I do is opening the required port in VPN provider web page and then open the port in my router and that's it.

Comment: You didn't answer my questions, and yes, daisy chaining VPN clients lans requires specific iptable rules.

Comment: Ok 
I did not add any iptables rules in my router , yes I can connect to the router , there is no overlapping in my network.
actually my network is very basic is consist of one router and just one alarm panel connected to the router LAN port and no other devices are using my VPN. I just need to open my alarm panel port so I can access it remotely using my VPN IP address.

Comment: It is unfortunately not that simple. You have 3 networks to deal with.  The LAN that the remote client is on, the VPN network itself, and your local LAN with the ddwrt router. The ddwrt router will reject incoming packets from the VPN by default - because it doesn't know how to bridge from the VPN subnet to the LAN subnet unless you explicitly configure it. It is running as a client, not a server. If the remote and local lans have the same subnet, routing will break regardless of the ddwrt settings. I can likely help you, but I'm not going to try to convince you of the nature of your task.

Comment: thank you for trying to help me, but before we proceed  may I ask why other VPN providers can do this without doing any network configuration from my side ?